# Numpy installed, but module not found

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pycharm

I've tried several fixes for this suggested in other threads, but no luck.

I'm new to Python.  I had 3.8.5 installed and wrote a few simple scripts that worked using PyCharm and the numpy and sympy modules.  Today I opened PyCharm and tried to write a simple script using numpy, but I got an error saying the numpy module did not exist.  I also got this error when trying to run the older scripts.  I checked in cmd with pip3, and got the result that it was already satisfied.  I uninstalled Python, numpy, and PyCharm, reinstalled all and I'm having the same problem.  This problem seemed to crop up on its own - I don't recall making any changes that would've caused this.

Can anyone give me other options?

Comment: You need to install Pandas !

Comment: 1) did you import it, e.g. `import numpy as np`?  2) do you know where the interpreter is?  Often multiple versions of python exist on a system, and something like `pip install numpy` might install it to a different version than you're using

Comment: In PyCharm go to File -> Settings -> Project: xxx -> Project Interpreter. Check the python version you are using in there. Add a screenshot here if you can. Then check the output of `pip3 --version`. If they are not similar, you need to change the interpreter in PyCharm or install numpy in the python version you're using in PyCharm project

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common issues with Python is having multiple versions installed and losing track of which one you are using and/or which one you're installing to with pip.

In Pycharm check what interpreter your project is using. If there is more than one available chance are you installed numpy on the other one.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter

You can also install numpy direct from Pycharm, simply hover over the import statement and if it's not installed on the current interpreter it will offer you a link to click in install it.

If that doesn't help, post the exact error message and your code.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to install numpy using the hover and click option you described.